# MySQL Join Query to get the sum of items in a cart table

Tags: mysql

this might be a really simple question but I'm trying to get the sum of the weight of items in my cart database by getting the some of the weight of the items from the products table. Im not really sure why its not working.

here is the query:

```
 SELECT sum(products.shipWeight) as totalweight
 FROM products 
 INNER JOIN Cart
 ON products.ProductCode = Cart.ProductCode
 AND Cart.purchaserID='9916' 
 AND Cart.cartActive = 'Yes'
```

this returns *NULL*

basically its trying to get the sum of shipWeight from all ProductCodes that exist in active 9916's cart.

im not sure if shipweight being a double has anything to do with it.

```
 SELECT sum(products.shipWeight) as totalweight
 FROM products
```

returns 485.2. So that tells me the sum is working

```
 SELECT * from cart
 where Cart.purchaserID='9916' 
 AND Cart.cartActive = 'Yes'
```

returns the record. So that tells me there is something still in the cart.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it returns `NULL` it means that the join didn't find any matching elements.

Comment: I think records are being returned based on his last statement. He's missing a group by clause also.

Comment: @andre3wap He doesn't need `GROUP BY` if he's getting the total for everything.

Comment: What is the ProductCode returned by the last query? Check if there's a record with that `ProductCode` in `products`. What is its `shipWeight`?

Comment: @Barmar - ah yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: oh man. i feel so dumb. Its because the item in the cart isnt in the products table. *face-palm* I really appreciate the assistance